# In Notes.app, how do you add columns to a table?

Tags: notes.app

I'm using Version 4.5 of Notes.app

There's an option to add a table. I see that if I tab through the table then rows will be added, but I'm not finding a way to add columns to the table.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is also support for hotkeys to "Add a new column to the right of the current column": Option-Command-Right Arrow
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/notes/apd46c25187e/mac#apd4184607ff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Add a table and click on it and you should get something that looks like this:

[image]

Notice the two small rectangles, One on the left of row 3 and the other on top of column 2. Right-click on these small rectangles and you'll be given an option to add row or column.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> will create column on the left or right

Answer (score 1):

As of macOS 12 Monterey the hotkey seems to be <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to "Add a new column to the right/left of the current column"

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/notes/apd46c25187e/mac#apd4184607ff